# Creating object DLL(C#) in VBA

Tags: c#, vba, object, dll

I've created dll and tlb file in C# to use it in VBA.
Code for dll looks like this:

```
using ModulPlanista.ServiceReference1;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ModulPlanista
{
    public class PlanistaMod
    {
        IiPlanistaServiceClient Planista;
        public bool ZaladowanoUsluge = false;
        List<UserViewUser> user = new List<UserViewUser>();
        EventsListRepsonse ListaEventow;
        long userID = 0;
        public int blad = 0;

        public PlanistaMod(string UserName)
        {
            try
            {
                Planista = new IiPlanistaServiceClient();
            }
            catch
            { 
                Planista = null;
                blad = -1;
                return;
            }
            try
            {
                user.AddRange(Planista.GetUsers(UserName));
                userID = GetUserID(UserName);
            }
            catch
            {
                user = new List<UserViewUser>();
                Planista = null;
                blad = -2;
                return;
            }
            try
            {
                ListaEventow = Planista.GetEventsList();
            }
            catch 
            {
                user = new List<UserViewUser>();
                Planista = null;
                blad = -3;
                return;
            }
            ZaladowanoUsluge = true;
        }       

        public string GetManufNumber(string UID)
        {
            return Planista.GetWoNoByUID(UID);
        }

    }
}
```

In C# I use dll like this:

```
using ModulPlanista;
namespace nPlanista
{
   public string GetManufacturerNo()
   {
        PlanistaMod module = new PlanistaMod(login);
        string manufacturerNo=planistaModule.GetManufNumber("1007177718");
   }
}
```

I have problem with creating object PlanistaMod, it isn't visible in VBA. I can only see references to web services (ModulPlanista.ServiceReference1), like in image below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wsjx2.png)

Any idea how to use dll?

Comment: I think VBA would use COM for interop. I'm fairly sure it cannot use regular .net types since it is not a .net language. See [Exposing .NET components to COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/exposing-dotnet-components-to-com)

Comment: Not absolutely sure this is what you are asking for, but if you are trying to use COM interop to call C# code from VBA then see [Calling C# code from VBA (COM interop)](https://www.thevbahelp.com/post/calling-c-sharp-code-from-vba-com-interop) (just for clarity, the link is to my site)

Comment: **JohnM** I've created dll from your website, next I used RegAsm tool to 'register for COM interop, I had tlb file, next I added reference to VBA.   But in line 'Set oMyStuff = New BlogProject.MyStuff', I've got error:Run-time error (80070002), Automation error .